# How do i select image resources for different screens while developing games?

Tags: android, android-screen-support

We use different drawable folders to deal with hdpi, mdpi ,xhdpi screens how can i deal with different screen sizes, this is to make sure images resources appear to be of same size.However in case of games this would make gaming harder on some devices and easier on others.

Also, the gaming experience might not be as good.

I was thinking about adding resources for different screen sizes but that would increase the size of game and does not appear to be a optimum way.

How can i proceed?

Comment: try `xlarge` `large` etc. qualifiers

Comment: Size of images would also depend on pixel density, so images would be of different sizes on xlarge, hdpi and xlarge,xxhdpi. Am i right?